# Unix - conversion from xls to csv - delay for big files

Tags: excel, csv, unix, converters, delay

for a new project I have to import Excel files to an Oracle database (globally, using Java).
After several researches on the web, the easiest way seems to transform xls to csv. The template of the file allows it.
I saw that several commands exist on Unix, like xls2csv. And the architecture of the project allows it.

My question : for big xls files, between 500.000 and 1.000.000 lines, do you know how long is the conversion, is it in seconds, minutes, hours ? 
And if it's exponential ? If 1 line takes 1 second, do 1.000 lines take 1.000 seconds ?

Regards,

Julien.

Comment: depends on the tool you use . you have to experiment and find . I would suggest use apache poi https://poi.apache.org/

Comment: Actually when I see advices around Apache POI, often conversion to csv is recommended. And as incoming files can be .xls or .csv, I think it's better to process both of them in the same way...